# How to bin a long continuous string into section of nth characters?

Tags: r

suppose I have a long continous string like this.

`x='aattggcccagtgtgtacaatcagtgcaggagctaatcccggactccttcgtcccctgtgtcgctgcgctgtgcagcgacgaagccgagcggctcactcgtctcaatcacctcagcttcgcggagctgcttaagcccttctcccgcctcacttccgaggttcacatgagagatcctaataatcaacttcacgtaattaaaaatttgaagatagcagtaagcaacattgtcacccagccacctcagcctggagccatccggaagcttttgaatgatgttgtttctggcagtcagcctgcagaaggattagtagctaatgtgattacagcaggagattatgaccttaacatcagtgAAAAAGCAAAGGACAAAAGATCTTTCTCGGGTGTTTCATTCTTACAGTCCATATGATCACAAGATTGGTGAAAGACAACAAGTGTTAGTAACAGAAGAATCTTTTGATTCCAAGTTTTATGTTGCACACAATCAATTCTATGAGCAGGTTTTAGTGCCAAAGAACCCTGCGTTCATGGGGAAGATGGTTGAAGTGGACATCTATGAATCAGGCAAACATTTTATGAAAGGGCAGCCAGTATCTGATGCCAAAGTGTACACGCCCTCCATCAGCAAACCGCTAGCAAAGGGAGAAGTCTCGGGTTTGACAAAGGACTTCAGAAATGGGCTTGGGAACCAGCTGAGTTCAGGATCCCACACCTCTGCTGCATCTCAGTGTGACTCAGCGAGTTCCAGAATGGTGCTGCCCATGCCAAGGCTACATCAAGACTGTGCGCTGAGGATGTCCGTGGGCTTGGCTCTGCTGGGTCTTCTTTTTGCTTTTTTTGTCAAGGTCTATAATTAGGGA'`

I would like to split this string into 10 characters with space in between. So far I tried this but its a bit clumsy and does'nt always bin the characters into 10

```
gregexpr(".{10}|.{9}|.{8}|.{7}|.{6}|.{5}|.{4}|.{3}|.{2}|.{1}", x ))[[1]]
```

the issue with the above code is when the string ends with anything other than 10 characters, nth-1 characters have to hard coded.

Comment: i think you are looking for 10-mers ( k-mers) its very important in genetics, especially the 3-mers (triplets)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a little bit cheesy, but:

```
c(                             ## drop "omit" attribute
  na.omit(                     ## drop NA values (from end)
    unlist(                    ## collapse from data frame to vector
       read.fwf(               ## read fixed-width "file"
            textConnection(x), ## treat string as a file
                 widths = rep(10,    ## string width
                               1000  ## a 'big enough' value
           )))))
```

Or if you like (in recent-ish versions of R that have `|>`)

```r
(x
   |> textConnection()
   |> read.fwf(widths = rep(10, 1000))
   |> unlist()
   |> na.omit()
   |> c()
)
```

Comment: ```|>``` something new. Now R looks like F? Is it a new trend?